# How to prevent browser from responding to scroll events

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have a Java applet which displays an interactive map. By using the scroll wheel the user can zoom in/out of the map. Unfortunately the web browser (Firefox) also responds to the scroll events, and the applet ends up being scrolled off the visible page.

My question is, how can I prevent the browser from responding when the mouse is within the boundaries of the applet?

So far I've tried modifying my HTML to make the applet request focus

```
applet.focus()
```

I also tried adding a statement to my applet's Java code like this

```
requestFocus();
```

But neither has resolved the problem.

I could add an specific zoom in/out control in the applet, or possibly restructure my web page to reduce the need for the web page to scroll, but it would be nice if the scroll wheel did the job of zooming the map only.

Comment: BTW anything that starts with *"How to prevent browser.."* is both not our right (to stuff with the user's browser) & not something you would attempt with Java (certainly not a sand-boxed applet) anyway.

Comment: Do you mean run the applet in a separate window? The applet interacts with other controls on the web page to filter what's displayed on the map.

Comment: A separate window - the applet viewer is used to display free-floating applets. *"The applet interacts with other controls on the web page"*  Thanks for clarifying - that is one of the few cases where an embedded applet makes sense (and it rules out the 'launch using web start' option).

Comment: @Andrew - Thanks, I agree with your comments about not messing with the browser behaviour. However I want the applet to capture all scroll events, specifically when the mouse is within its boundaries. I like Matthew's answer, will try it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use javascript and do something like this:

```
var applet = document.getElementById("appletID");
applet.mouseover = function(e) {
    document.body.onscroll = function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
    }
}

applet.mouseout = function(e) {
    //replace with empty function
    document.body.onscroll = function(e) { }
}
```

not this is untested code. might be a couple typos

EDIT like i said typos... I tested this and it works for sure:

```
window.onload = function() {

var applet = document.getElementById("header");
    applet.onmouseover = function(e) {
         window.onscroll = function(e) {
         //scroll where you want to be (the top)
           scroll(0,0) ;
         }
     }

    applet.onmouseout = function(e) {
          //replace with empty function
          window.onscroll = function(e) {}
    }

};
```

Using the scroll method is not as clean but preventDefault didn't seem to work...

Comment: +1.  I think JS is the only way this can be made to work for a sand-boxed applet.

Comment: Great idea, and accepted, but for some reason my onscroll function never gets called. I set a breakpoint on e.preventDefault() and it's never hit. Possibly some other JS code is setting a different onscroll function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried attaching a MouseListener to the container that displays the map and then have your container requestFocus()?